# Relation Duration x Work x Start Date x End Date in MS Project 2007

Tags: project-management, ms-project

Well, i'm beginner in MS Project (specifically in MS Project 2007) and a i got the following problem:

```
 1 - I have all tasks maped in "Grantt Charts". 
 2 - My workday is 14 hours per week (monday to monday, without holidays). 
 3 - The work schedule is from 21:00PM to 23:00PM, so calculating this we have: 

(2h per day) X (7 days in a week) = 14h per week.
```

**The big problem is**: When i put 7 days in column durating (in any task) the work shows 14h (this is correct) but the start date and end date just count 1, my ideia is that for MS PROJECT 1 day have 8h of work (and not 2h as i wanna), so 14h is like 1,75 days, but should be exact 7 days because my project is like that, only 2h per day and not 8h per day as MS PROJECT think.

Answer (score 1):

There is an independant setting in MS-Project that tells the system how many hours you consider there to be in a working day. In your case it should be 2, not the default of 7.

Go to "Change Working Time" on the Tools menu. Click the "Options" button. Change the field entitled "Hours per day" to 2.